# $\omega$ a continuous $m$-form in $M$, $\dim M=m$, $M$ is orientable $\iff \omega \neq 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

Let $M$ a surface, $\dim M=m$, and let $\omega$  a continuous $m-$form in $M$. I want to prove that $M$ is orientable $\iff \omega(x)\neq 0\; \forall x\in M$.

The $(\Leftarrow)$ part is ok to me, since I say [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748845/a-m-dimensional-differentiable-manifold-that-has-a-non-zero-continuous-m-for) post. However, I don't know exactly how to prove the $(\Rightarrow) $ part, even if it looks  kind of obvious.

I tried to taking two parametrizations $\phi,\psi$ of $x\in M$ in an orientation of $M$ and work with writting $\omega$ in each basis, but I don't know exactly how to proceed.
Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement as written is false. On any manifold (orientable or otherwise), there exists a continuous $m$-form that is equal to zero everywhere. That is a trivial counterexample.

I think the statement should say, if $M$ is orientable then **there exists** a continuous $m$-form $\omega$ such that $\omega(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in M$.

To construct this $m$-form, I suggest you take a positively-oriented atlas, and construct positive-valued $m$-forms locally in each coordinate chart. Then multiply these local $m$-forms by a partition of unity (so that they can be extended continuously to the entire manifold), and add them together. Use the fact that the Jacobian determinants are positive (since the charts are positively-oriented with respect to each other) to conclude that the sum of the local $m$-forms is also positive in each chart.

Comment: I understood the idea, and I'm trying to write it.
Basically I take one point $x\in M$ and two parametrizations of $x$ in an orientation of $M$.
In the intersection of these parametrizations, I define $\omega(x)=a(x)\textrm{d}u_1\wedge\dots\wedge\textrm{d}u_m$, with $a(x)$ being the determinant of the Jacobian of parametrization changing.
$\omega$ is a continuous $m$-form in $M$ with $\omega(x)\neq 0$.
And so I can use partitions of unity to extend this $a$ for the whole $M$, not just the neighborhood.
Is that your idea?

Comment: I just have one question about it:
How can I ensure that exist such $x$? 
Maybe my orientation is some kind of atlas of a locally connected surface, and I just have one chart per connected component, and in this case I can't take such $x$.

Comment: @MateusRocha My idea is as follows. Take a *positively-oriented* atlas $(U_i, \phi_i)$ (where the $U_i$ are open subsets of $M$, and the $\phi_i : U_i \to \mathbf R^m$ are coordinate parametrisations, and where the Jacobians ${\rm Jac} (\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1})$ for the coordinate transformations are all strictly positive since the charts are positively oriented).

Comment: Now let the functions $\psi_i : M \to \mathbf R$  be a partition of unity subordinate to the open cover $\{ U_i \}$. That is, for each $i$, the function $\psi_i$ is supported in the open set $U_i$, and $0 \leq \psi_i (x) \leq 1$ for each $x$ and $i$, and $\sum_i \psi_i(x) = 1$ for each $x$, with only finitely many $\psi_i$'s contributing to the sum for each $x$.

Comment: On each $U_i$, I define an $m$-form $\alpha_i$ as the $m$-form that has the representation $dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_m$ under the coordinate representation $\phi_i: U_i \to \mathbf R^m$. This $\alpha_i$ is only smooth on $U_i$, but if I multiply it by $\psi_i$ (which is supported on $U_i$), then I get $\psi_i \alpha_i$, which is smooth on the whole of $M$.

Comment: Finally, I define $\omega := \sum_i \psi_i \alpha_i$, which is smooth on the whole of $M$. And it is non-zero everywhere. To see that it is non-zero everywhere, let's write it out in the $i$th chart. In the $i$th chart, it has the representation $\sum_i \psi_i (x) {\rm Jac } (\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}) (x) dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_m $. All of the Jacobians are positive, and for each $x$, at least one $\psi_i$ is positive, so $\sum_i \psi_i (x) {\rm Jac } (\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}) (x)$ is positive for every $x$. Hence $\omega$ is everywhere non-vanishing.

Comment: I got it!
I just dont know why in the $i$th chart, $\omega$ has that representation. The sum is in the index $i$, so maybe this is the representation of the $j$th chart, right?

Comment: It's simply that if $\omega = f(y) dy_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dy_m$ on chart $U_j$, then $\omega = f(\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}(x)) {\rm Jac}(\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1})(x) dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_m $ on chart $U_i$. Jacobians are used to perform coordinate transformations on $m$-forms.